# c# program closes and restarts if I run the .exe by double click or cmd

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, cmd

Hello I have a weird bug in my application.

I have build an c# script which opens a form. Well if I run the .exe from visual studio everything works great but if I run the .exe by doubleclick or from the cmd the program stays for 5-10 seconds and than restarts the form again and stays untill I close the programm. The project is a windows forms application.

Comment: Use try-catch block to get the exception which would tell you why the program terminates.

Comment: I also created a empty forms application and started it and it also restarts itself so I think its a cmd problem what I got here.

Comment: When you start the app out of VS, Do you start it in debugging mode or normally?

Comment: Do you have Windows 8?

Comment: Yes I start in debugging mode. If I start it without debugging mode the same error happens again. @OrkunBekar: No its windows 7.

Comment: Do you have Avast Antivirus? :)

Comment: Yes I have avast antivirus

Comment: If you have multiple projects in the one solution, do you have the right project set as the start project?

Comment: @OrkunBekar: It was really the avast antivirus. After uninstalling it the bug disappeared. Can you please write it as an answer so I can check the question as done? Cok sagolasin kardes

Comment: You're welcome. :) önemli değil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I several times faced that problem and I realised that Avast Antivirus causing that issue. If you disable or uninstall it you will get rid of the error.